# jQuery div element scroll animation with next/prev button untill the end of all element

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll, sliding

I want to stop my scrolling element when it reaches at certain position or end of total width and next button should be disable if there is no more scrolling condition and same for previous button.
Everything working fine in below code but i have tried some if() condition before animate but none of them are working my scroller is going on and on.
Please check following example :

```
var lists = $(".contents");
                for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i += 4) {
                    j = i + 1;
                    lists.slice(i, i + 4).wrapAll("<div id='newDivforWraping" + j + "' class='new'></div>");
                }
                var total_width = $(".new").width();
                //alert(total_width);
                $(".scroller").width(total_width * 3);

                $(".next").click(function() {
                    //alert("hi");

                    if ($(".scroller").css("margin-left") !== -1160) {
                        $(".scroller").animate({
                            marginLeft: "-=580"
                        });
                    } else {
                        alert("1160");
                    }
                });
                $(".prev").click(function() {
                    //alert("hi");
                    $(".scroller").animate({
                        left: "+=580"
                    });
                });

            });
```

Demo : 
http://jsfiddle.net/gsmwe3/65VRm/1/

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution for above question but still bullet navigation is remaining if anyone know how to add bullets to navigate slides.
look at fiddle

```
var lists = $(".contents");
                for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i += 12) {
                    j = i + 1;
                    lists.slice(i, i + 12).wrapAll("<div id='newDivforWraping" + j + "' class='new'></div>");
                }
                var total_slides = $(".scroller div").length;
                var single_width = $(".new").width();
                $(".scroller").width(single_width * total_slides);
                var xPos = $('.scroller div:last').position();
                var pos = '-' + xPos.left + 'px';
                $(".next").click(function() {
                    if ($(".scroller").css("left") < "0") {
                        $(".scroller").animate({
                            left: "+=988"
                        }, 500);
                    }
                }
                );
                $(".prev").click(function() {
                    if ($(".scroller").css("left") > pos) {
                        $(".scroller").animate({
                            left: "-=988"
                        }, 500);
                    }
                });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gsmwe3/65VRm/